# How do I iterate over an array in a nested json object in sqlite?

Tags: arrays, json, sqlite

Assume I have a sqlite table `features` which has a column `data` that contains json objects.

`CREATE TABLE features ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, data json )`

Now, an example data object may be:

```
{"A":
   {"B":
      {"coordinates":[
         {"x":1, "y":10},
         {"x":10, "y":2},
         {"x":12, "y":12}
       ]
    }
}
```

Now the number of json objects in the `coordinates` array can vary from row to row. Some documents can have 3 coordinates (example above) while others may have 5 or more coordinates.

For each row or document, I want to be able to iterate over just the `x` values and find the minimum, same for `y` values. So the results for the example would be 1 for x and 2 for y.

I can get all the json objects inside the array using `json_each` but I can't extract x for just one single row. I tried:

```
select value from features, json_each(json_extract(features.data, '$.A.B.coordinates'));
```

However, this seems to return "all" `coordinate` json objects for all rows. How do I go about iterating the array for one document and extract values from it so I can then select a minimum or maximum for one document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `json_extract()` again after `json_each(json_extract())` to extract each `x` and `y` and aggregate:

```
SELECT f.id, 
       MIN(json_extract(value, '$.x')) x, 
       MIN(json_extract(value, '$.y')) y
FROM features f, json_each(json_extract(f.data, '$.A.B.coordinates'))
GROUP BY f.id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4d2131ab33896e890afd7cd908323124).